# linear ordinary differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this linear ode:
$$y''+\dfrac{4x}{x^2-1 }y'+\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}y=0 $$
I tried few variables changing but I did not get any result.
thanks

Answer (score 10):

Note that
\begin{align}
&(x^2-1)y''+4x y'+(x^2+1)y=\\
=&(x^2-1)y''+2(x^2-1)'y'+(x^2-1)''y+(x^2-1)y=\\
=&[(x^2-1)y]''+(x^2-1)y.
\end{align}
Therefore if we write $\displaystyle y(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x^2-1}$, the equation becomes
$$f''+f=0.$$

Comment: That's very nice!